# Some times not able to login into my system after I do remote desktop from other system

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

If I do remote desktop on my system from others computer, sometimes it is not allowing me to login into my system (directly), though I have closed my remote desktop session.

I am using windows XP professional with service pack 3.

Comment: More info - what do you mean you can't log in?  Do you get an error, does the screen freeze, does it reject your credentials?

Comment: @JNK - I am getting error like "only or administrator can login into the system"

Comment: You say you 'closed' your remote session, but did you actually log out?  If not, try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the problem with the OS image which are provided in my company and it got resolved in the latest image.

Save the below contents as screensaver.reg and double click to resolve the issue.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaveTimeOut"="300"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="1"
"SCRNSAVE.EXE"="scrnsave.scr"
"ScreenSaveActive"="1"
"ScreenSaveTimeOut"="300"

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaveActive"="1"
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="1"
"ScreenSaveTimeout"="300"
"SCRNSAVE.EXE"="scrnsave.scr"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system]
"NoDispScrSavPage"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors you gave, it sounds like your local account is not an admin but the remote account was - it locked your PC and you need admin privileges to unlock.

Bear in mind that remote desktop ALWAYS locks the remote PC with a message that says "This computer is in use and has been locked - only  or an admin can unlock it".  You may be getting this error if you don't disconnect your RDP session.

Comment: My account have admin privileges and I disconnected RDP session too. but still I am facing this error.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or exact quote of the error?

Comment: "only or administrator can login into the system" this is the exact error I am getting,.

Comment: @Thang - No offense but that is not an actual error code.  Can you copy/paste it here?  What you put is CLOSE to an error code, but it's not exact.  Also at what point does it come up?  Is it there before you do anything, or only after you try to log in?